# service variable is null when accessing from main class

Tags: java, spring, swing, service, applicationcontext

I have a swing class called App.java, in there I have this:

```
private EmployeeService employeeService;

public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}
```

and in my applicationContext.xml, I have this:

```
<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.myapp.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="employeeService" class="com.myapp.service.EmployeeServiceImpl">
    <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="app" class="com.myapp.swing.App">
    <property name="employeeService" ref="employeeService" />
</bean>
```

When I run App.java, I am receiving the error that employeeService is null. Why is that so? If I assign the employeeService bean directly from the class:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/applicationContext.xml");
EmployeeService employeeService = (EmployeeService) context.getBean("employeeService");
employeeService.validateEmployeeNo(1234);
context.close();

...
```

I am able to run it successfully. Isn't spring wiring employeeService in App.java when I inject it from applicationContext.xml?

Comment: are you seeing any error? maybe the applicationContext.xml is not even read/parsed.

Comment: Your applicationContext.xml file looks right. Are you sure spring is being initialized when you run your application normally?

Comment: I guess it is, cos by calling employeeService from the App class it would also call employeeDao that calls dataSource, and I don't get problems there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your App class is being created by the Spring container you are going to get null on any service you try to access.  How are you initializing your App class?

```
App myApp = new App();
```

or

```
App myApp = (App) context.getBean("app");
```

Comment: I am not. It actually is my main swing class that has the public static void main method. Could it be the reason?I am not. It actually is my main swing class that has the public static void main method. Could it be the reason?